# CakePHP 3 - How to insert a record without auto increment primary key ID

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I am working with a legacy table schema which has a primary key that is not a standard auto-incrementing id. Instead, the primary key is VARCHAR(15) in the format:

```
ABC10001
ABC10002
ABC10003
ABC10004
ABC10005
```

Is there a way to set up the model Table so that it automatically generates the next ID in the sequence when inserting a new row?

Comment: What have you tried? What's the problem with saving an entity that has a primary key value set in that format?

Comment: @ndm Just wondering if there is a clean way of setting up the Table class to automatically find the last ID, increment the number and use that as the primary key when inserting. Rather than trying to manually set the ID every time in a controller or whatever. Just pitching the question in advance so I have some ideas when I come to start the work.

Comment: I see, but that makes it a different question, at least in its current form it's not not immediately obvious that this is what you are looking for :) I'd suggest to edit your question so that it reflects your actual needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to set up the model Table so that it automatically generates the next ID in the sequence when inserting a new row?

Use the [beforeSave()](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/table-objects.html#beforesave) callback and implement a method to generate the next id.

```
public function beforeSave(Event $event, EntityInterface $entity) {
     if ($entity->isNew()) {
         $entity->id = $this->generateId();
     }
}

public function generateId() {
    // Your implementation here.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally, in order to generate custom, new primary key values, you could either use

- a custom type class that implements/overrides `\Cake\Database\Type::newId()`
- an overridden `\Cake\ORM\Table::_newId()` method in the respective table class, which by default asks the type associated with the column for a new ID (via `Type::newId()`)
- the `Model.beforeSave` callback
- or a trigger in your database

In your case you'd need to have access to a specific repository, so the type class feels like the wrong place, as it would hardly be usable accross different repositories, considering that type instances are being reused and configured globally.

Personally I'd probably go with triggers in order to ensure integrity at the top most level, and in case they cannot be used for whatever reason, chose the second option, as it is only invoked where it's needed, that is, right before data is being inserted, and the generated value is only being used in case the data doesn't already contain a primary key value. All you'd need to do, is to read the last/highest ID, and return it incremented by `1`.

See

- **[API > \Cake\Database\Type::newId()](http://api.cakephp.org/3.2/class-Cake.Database.Type.html#_newId)**
- **[API > \Cake\ORM\Table::_newId()](http://api.cakephp.org/3.2/class-Cake.ORM.Table.html#__newId)**
- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Table Objects > Lifecycle Callbacks > beforeSave](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/table-objects.html#beforesave)**
- **[Google > Database Triggers](https://www.google.com/search?q=database+triggers&oq=database+triggers)**